# How would i use a quantitative data site like coinmarketcap.com?

Tags: alternatives, speculation, currencies

I understand that I could calculate my hashrate and thus expected profitability per hardware speed, but I don't understand how to valuate what market price 'should' be and how to actually valuate an alt-coin.  I am trying to get past feelings based speculation and want feedback from what other crypto day traders do.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand... are you trying to use the data from that site to determine what alt-coins 'should' be selling for vs what they are selling for?

Comment: Exactly - I just want to know what they 'should' be sold for.

Comment: I believe that that question of how much money something "should" cost is fundamentally unanswerable. If there were a way to answer that, the market would reach a point where there would be noting to gain from selling or buying and the speculation market would collapse. There are two ways to succeed at speculation: one is luck; the other is by possessing and acting upon knowledge that others do not. So if you want to get past feelings based speculation, you're need to research the market in order to understand how and why bitcoin is used.